# R raster calculate areal weighted mean when scaling to a larger resolution with offset

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have two raster grids in R with different resolutions which don't line up exactly. In actual fact I have hundreds of each so any answer must be easily run many times.

I want to scale the finer resolution grid up to the coarser resolution by taking an areal weighted mean of the grid cells.

I was hoping I could use `projectRaster` or `resample` but neither give the desired output and I cannot use aggregate as I need my new grids to align to the coarser resolution grid.

For my real data my finer grid is 0.005 deg intervals and coarser is at  0.02479172 deg intervals and extents/origins don't exactly match up.

I've made an extreme version as an example why neither resample or projectRaster work

```r
library(raster)
#> Warning: package 'raster' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Loading required package: sp

testproj <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100 +ellps=WGS84"


testmat <- matrix(1, nrow = 8, ncol = 8)
# testmat <- matrix(sample(1:10, 64, replace = T), nrow = 8, ncol = 8)
testmat[1,5] <- 400
testmat[8,4] <- -400

testsmallraster <- raster(testmat, xmn=0, xmx=8, ymn=0, ymx=8)
crs(testsmallraster) <- testproj
plot(testsmallraster)
```

[image]

```r
testlarger <- raster(matrix(rep(NA,4), nrow = 2, ncol = 2), xmn=0.3, xmx=8.3, ymn=0, ymx=8)

crs(testlarger) <- testproj

tout_reproj <- projectRaster(testsmallraster, testlarger)
tout_resamp <- resample(testsmallraster, testlarger)
tout_resampngb <- resample(testsmallraster, testlarger, method = "ngb")
tout_agg <- aggregate(testsmallraster, fact = 4)

#reprojected values ignore all but 4 cells closest to new centre 
values(tout_reproj)
#> [1] 1 1 1 1
#resample uses bilinear interpolation which weights the grids cells furthest from the new centre less than those closest
# I need all grid cells entirely contained in the new grid to have equal weighting
#bilinear interpolation also weights cells which do not fall within the new cell at all which I do not want
values(tout_resamp)
#> [1]  10.851852  15.777778  -7.911111 -12.366667
#aggregate gives close to the values I want but they are not in the new raster origin/resolution and therefore not splitting values that fall across grid boundaries
values(tout_agg)
#> [1]   1.0000  25.9375 -24.0625   1.0000
#using ngb was never really going to make any sense but thought I'd as it for completeness
values(tout_resampngb)
#> [1] 1 1 1 1


#desired output first cell only 0.3 of a grid cell covers the grid cell = 400 the rest equal 1
#desired output second cell 0.7 of a grid cell covers the grid cell = 400 the rest equal 1
#desired output third cell has exactly 1 grid cell of -400 and 15 of 1
#desired output fourth cell only overlap grid cells = 1 
desiredoutput <- raster(matrix(c((15.7*1+0.3*400)/16,(15.3*1+0.7*400)/16,mean(c(-400, rep(1,15))),1),byrow = T, nrow = 2, ncol = 2), xmn=0.3, xmx=8.3, ymn=0, ymx=8)
values(desiredoutput)
#> [1]   8.48125  18.45625 -24.06250   1.00000
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can get closer to the desired result by using a similar spatial resolution for `resample`, and then aggregate the results

```
library(raster)
testproj <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100 +datum=WGS84"
testmat <- matrix(1, nrow = 8, ncol = 8)
testmat[1,5] <- 400
testmat[8,4] <- -400
testsmallraster <- raster(testmat, xmn=0, xmx=8, ymn=0, ymx=8, crs=testproj)
testlarger <- raster(matrix(rep(NA,4), nrow = 2, ncol = 2), xmn=0.3, xmx=8.3, ymn=0, ymx=8, crs = testproj)

y <- disaggregate(testlarger, 4)
z <- resample(testsmallraster, y)
za <- aggregate(z, 4)
values(za)
#[1]   8.48125  18.45625 -24.06250   1.00000
```

for much better speed, try `terra`

```
library(terra)
a <- rast(testsmallraster)
b <- rast(testlarger)
b <- disaggregate(b, 4)
d <- resample(a, b)
da <- aggregate(d, 4)
values(da)
#         layer
#[1,]   8.48125
#[2,]  18.45625
#[3,] -24.06250
#[4,]   1.00000
```

This probably ought to be done automatically by resample and project(Raster). `raster` attempts to do some of this for resample, but in this case not very satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to do similar resampling, this worked for me.  This example is a 4-cell destination grid at 1o x 1o spacing with centroids at half degrees (to match some satellite data), and an offset half-degree grid for source data (ECMWF weather).  'Resample' does the heavy lifting of interpolating on mismatched grids.   The code below is basically a manual version of a 'weights=' option that doesn't exist for resample.   We need relative, not absolute, areas to be correct for weighting, so the caveat on the precision of raster::area described in the help seems of low concern.

```
library(raster)
wgs84 <- "+init=epsg:4326"

polar.brick.source <- array(dim = c(5, 5, 2), rep(c(1, 2), each = 25))
dimnames(polar.brick.source)[[1]] <- seq(-1, 1, by = .5)
dimnames(polar.brick.source)[[2]] <- seq(80, 82, by = .5)
dimnames(polar.brick.source)[[3]] <- c("time.a", "time.b")
# Add some outliers to see their effects.    
polar.brick.source[1, 2, ] <- c(25, 50)
polar.brick.source[3, 2, 2] <- -30
polar.brick <- brick(polar.brick.source, crs = CRS(wgs84),
   xmn = min(as.numeric(dimnames(polar.brick.source)[[1]])) - .25,
   xmx = max(as.numeric(dimnames(polar.brick.source)[[1]])) + .25,
   ymn = min(as.numeric(dimnames(polar.brick.source)[[2]])) - .25,
   ymx = max(as.numeric(dimnames(polar.brick.source)[[2]])) + .25)
fine.polar.area <- raster::area(polar.brick)

polar.one.degree.source <- data.frame(
   lon = c(-.5,  .5, -.5,  .5),
   lat = c(80.5, 80.5, 81.5, 81.5),
    placeholder = rep(1, 4))
polar.one.degree.raster <- rasterFromXYZ(polar.one.degree.source, crs = CRS(wgs84))
polar.one.degree.area <- raster::area(polar.one.degree.raster)
as.data.frame(polar.one.degree.area, xy = T)

fine.clip.layer <- disaggregate(polar.one.degree.raster, 2)
clipped.fine.polar <-resample(polar.brick * fine.polar.area,
   fine.clip.layer)
new.weighted.wx <- aggregate(clipped.fine.polar * 4, 2)
as.data.frame(new.weighted.wx, xy = T) # look at partial results.
new.weather <- new.weighted.wx / polar.one.degree.area
as.data.frame(new.weather, xy = T)
```